# How to draw an arrow between two widgets (QPushButton) in pyqt or pyside?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, pyside, pyside2

I am trying to build a Qt app with python, that has a tree diagram where the nodes are buttons.
At the moment, a simple example of the widget (wihtout the arrows) I am building would be the following:

```py
class MyWidget(QScrollArea):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()  
        
        baselayout = QVBoxLayout()
        baselayout.addWidget(QPushButton("Button 0"))
        layout1 = QHBoxLayout()
        layout1.addWidget(QPushButton("Button 1"))
        layout1.addWidget(QPushButton("Button 2"))
        baselayout.addLayout(layout1)
    
        self.widget = QWidget()
        self.widget.setLayout(baselayout)
        self.setWidget(self.widget)
```

Is there a way I could display an arrow from 'Button 0' and 'Button 1', and another between 'Button 0' and 'Button 2'? I have not found any way this could be done.

Comment: You could do it with a custom widget, but the reality is that such "graph" layouts should be implemented using the [Graphics View Framework](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/graphicsview.html).